# Get the value of name key from the list of dictionaries return by the annotate and then sort by name?

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion, django-queryset, django-annotate, django-2.x

My Code

```
def get_areas(self, obj):
        text = []
        if obj.areas and not obj.areas == []:
            print(json.loads(obj.area_count))
            print(type(obj.area_count))
            return json.loads(obj.area_count)
        return "-"

get_areas.short_description = "Areas"
get_areas.admin_order_field= "area_count"

def get_queryset(self, request):
        from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform
        qs = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        filtered_query = qs.filter(
            is_superuser=False, is_staff=False
        ).annotate(
            wishlist_count=Count('wishlist', distinct=True),
            booking_count=Count('booking', distinct=True),
            review_count=Count('review', distinct=True),
            suggestion_count=Count('suggestion', distinct=True),
            home_city=NullIf('home__city'),
            home_country=NullIf('home__country'),              
            area_count = F('areas'),

        )
```

What i get is a list as a str type which looks something like:

```
"[{'id': 98, 'name': 'Khalifa City and Masdar City', 'city': 'Abu Dhabi'},
{'id': 99, 'name': 'Masdar City', 'city': 'Abu Dhabi'}]"
<class 'str'>
```

What I want is the list of names instead:

```
['Khalifa City and Masdar City','Madsar City']
```

So, how to return the result by `area_count = F('areas')` as **list** instead of **str**

**Note:** The list can contain more than 1 dictionary and I want to return just the names.Any effort would be appreciated

Comment: You're returning a Dictionary (or JSON object), not a string

Comment: I am TRYING to return a dictionary object but not able to return it @TimothyWong as F('areas') returns the list of dictionary as a string thats what causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you need an `annotate` by `F("areas")` for?

Just remove it and access "areas" as an attr on the object in QS.

Comment: What about the admin_order_field then? what should be I pass into that?

Comment: I have made some changes in the question that helps you understand that areas is not the only field I am annotating so I can't take "areas" as an attr as I will not get anything to define for the admin_order_field

Comment: @ChetanVashisth it should be available on the instance w/o the use of `F`.

Comment: '[{"Name":'CV',"class":"hello"},{"Name":'NYC',"class":"hello"}]' this is the string stored in the charfield and i want to sort by the name field so how can we do that??? @Krzysztof Szularz

Comment: Sort it in Python.

Comment: I can do that but is there a way to override django's sorting functionality by any means/